# Update and Delete function not Working Asp.net MVC React

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

i am creating the simple crud operation on Asp.net MVC Core along with React.i could add the records and view the records successfully. but i couldn't delete and update the records. i checked through postman it is working fine i could delete and update the records when i tested through React update and delete function are not working.what i tried so far i attached below.

**Error show us on the console**

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () this error is throwing on the console
```

**StudentController.cs**

```
     using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using webb.Model;

namespace webb.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class StudentController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly StudentDbContext _studentDbContext;


     
        [HttpPatch]
        [Route("UpdateStudent")]
        public async Task<Student> UpdateEmployee(Student objStudent)
        {
            _studentDbContext.Entry(objStudent).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await _studentDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            return objStudent;
        }

        [HttpDelete]
        [Route("DeleteStudent")]
        public bool DeleteEmployee(int id)
        {
            bool result = false;
            var student = _studentDbContext.Student.Find(id);
            if (student != null)
            {
                _studentDbContext.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                _studentDbContext.SaveChanges();
                result = true;
            }
            else
            {
                result = false;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

**React Code**

```
  async function DeleteEmployee(id) {
 

  await axios.delete("https://localhost:7205/api/Student/DeleteStudent" + id);
   alert("Employee deleted Successfully");
   Load();
  }
 
  async function update(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {

  await axios.patch("https://localhost:7205/api/Student/UpdateStudent"+ employees.find((u) => u.id === id).id || id,
        {
        id: id,
        stname: stname,
        course: course,
      
        }
      );
      alert("Registation Updateddddd");
     
      Load();
    } catch (err) {
      alert(err);
    }
  }
 
  return (
```

Check Through Swagger
**Update**
[image]

**Delete**
[image]

**Program.cs**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using webb.Model;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();


builder.Services.AddDbContext<StudentDbContext>(options =>
   options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("StudentDbContext")));

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors(policy => policy.AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
                            .AllowCredentials());


// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: can you show  request status in network tab

Comment: ya sureeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () this error is throwing on the console tab

Comment: Share your full controller class code snippet and `program.cs` with cors configuration.

Comment: i updated full code of the controller

Comment: i updated the program.cs code

Comment: if you call Delete api with query string of id you should set `FromUri` in api. or you can change route to `[Route("DeleteStudent/{id}")]` and in front `await axios.delete("https://localhost:7205/api/Student/DeleteStudent/" + id);`

Comment: thanks workinggggggggggggggggggggggggg

Comment: one hint that i can tell you to compare is check the diffrence between request in network tab of swagger and react, like url, httperb and etc to be exactly the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like as said in comment:

if you call Delete api with query string of id you should set `FromUri` in api.

or you can change route to `[Route("DeleteStudent/{id}")]` and in front `await axios.delete("https://localhost:7205/api/Student/DeleteStudent/" + id);`