# Http 405 MethodNotAllowed on ASP.NET Core endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, vue.js, asp.net-core, vuejs2

Vs.js code - here are axios.delete and mounted sections:

```
mounted() {    
    this.getCreated();
},

deleteRequest(id) {
   axios.delete("http://localhost:32961/api/request/delete"+id)
      .then(() => {
        this.getCreated()
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
},
```

C# code - this is the backend part (controller):

```
[Route("delete/{id}")]
[HttpDelete]
public IActionResult Delete([FromBody] Request request)
{    
    _db_Context.Requests
               .FirstOrDefault(a => a.RequestId == request.RequestId);

    _db_Context.Requests.Remove(request);
    _db_Context.SaveChanges();

    return Ok(request);
}
```

I think I'm making a mistake in the vue.js axios.delete part. I am getting error code 405. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
axios.delete("http://localhost:32961/api/request/delete"+id)
```

to

```
axios.delete("http://localhost:32961/api/request/delete/"+id)
```

And do this in the C# API code:

```
[Route("delete/{id}")]
[HttpDelete]
public IActionResult Delete(int id)
{    
    _db_Context.Requests
               .FirstOrDefault(a => a.RequestId == request.RequestId);

    _db_Context.Requests.Remove(request);
    _db_Context.SaveChanges();

    return Ok(request);
}
```

Or if you call Delete API with query string of id you should set `FromUri` in api.

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74968236/5214219)

Answer (score 0):

Abbas Aryanpour is right in pointing out the missing `/` in your code. But I think the error message should be 404, not 405.

I think this should be related to your asp.net core back-end code not setting cross-domain, or you have set cross-domain, but did not notice the execution order of middleware, so it may cause cross-domain not to take effect.

**Official doc:**

[1.Troubleshoot connection errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-6.0#response-code-405)

[2. Cross-origin resource sharing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/security?view=aspnetcore-6.0#cross-origin-resource-sharing)